# R studio expected ',' after expression

Tags: r, rstudio

R studio のスクリプト上で、例えば下記のように、カンマを打つべき行で打たないと、
その行の一番左に、バツ印が表示されます。
このバツ印にカーソルを合わせると、「R studio expected ',' after expression」
というエラーが、表示されます。

```
 　m <- rbind(
x   　revenue
x   　expenses
x   　profit.1000
x  　 profit.margin
   　good.months
　 )
```

一行一行カンマを打てば、エラーが出なくなりますが、まとめて複数行にカンマを
打つ方法は無いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

RStudioはその手の便利なショートカット多いですよ！

ご指摘の機能はマルチラインカーソル機能で一瞬で出来ます。

「Alt/Option」を押しながら、マウスで x の付いた行の何処かをなぞってみて下さい。
カーソルが、複数行に点滅します。

そのままカーソルを右端に移動したら、カンマを打つと表示されてるカーソル全てにカンマが入力されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 既に存在するベクトルや配列から、定義するコードを作りたい場合は datapasta パッケージも便利ですよ。　https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html